# how to remove hover effect when navigation bar effect

Tags: javascript, html

how to remove hover effect when navigation bar effect

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#">BUSINESS EXCHANGE</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">DIRECTORY</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">LEO STORE</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONVENTION</a></li>
  </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

```
#logo {
    height: 115px;
    margin-left: 95%;
    margin-top: -13px;
}

.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 47px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    height: 120px;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse,
.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin: -102px 62px 0px 192px;
}
```

Comment: What is your CSS? Is there any library here?

Comment: plese help to remove zoop effect when tag is active

Comment: #logo {
  height: 115px;
margin-left: 95%;
margin-top: -13px;
}
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 47px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
 height: 120px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    margin: -102px 62px 0px 192px;
}

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the hover effect on the navbar in the bootstrap file.

Otherwise you can do it like this:

```
.navbar:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #999999;
}
```

Add this following CSS after the core bootstrap CSS file.

Comment: how to remove zoom effect from that

Comment: Try to do .navbar:hover, .navbar:focus { display: none; }